# Replacing a certain word in a string from a string matrix with java

Tags: java, string, oop

so I got this task that I need to do and what I am trying to complete is changing a word from a String, to an abbreviation of a word.
The word and an abbreviation is stored in a two dimensional matrix and. Here's the code I already got, but it does not work.

```
String[][] abriev = {{"United Kingdom", "kilometers"}, {"UK", "km"}};

String origText = "The;coastline;of;United Kingdom;is;12429;kilometers";

int n = origText.length();
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++){

   origText = origText.replaceAll(";", " ");      

   if (origText.toLowerCase().contains(abriev[i][0])){

       origText = origText.replaceAll(abriev[i][0], abriev[0][i]);
   }
}

System.out.println(origText);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're string looks like it's designed to be easily split, and you could iterate over that, do the replacement, and append it to a `StringBuilder`.

As for the string 2d array, you could easily convert that into a Map and set the key to be the word you're searching for, and the value.

In your code you actually reset the changes you make by calling `[0][i]` as the second parameter in `replaceAll()`;

What I would do would be this:

```
String[][] abriev = {{"United Kingdom", "kilometers"}, {"UK", "km"}};

    String origText = "The;coastline;of;United Kingdom;is;12429;kilometers";
    HashMap<String, String> wordAbbr = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < abriev[0].length; i++ )
    {
        wordAbbr.put(abriev[0][i], abriev[1][i]);
    }
    String [] origArr = origText.split(";");
    String output = "";
    for(String s : origArr){
        if(wordAbbr.get(s)!=null) {
            output = output + " " + wordAbbr.get(s);
        }else {
            output = output + " " + s;
        }
    }
    output = output + ".";

    System.out.println(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd convert `abriev` to a `Map` for easier lookups. Then, I'd take original text, split it by the `;` character, stream it, replace each word with its abbreviation (if available), and re-join the stream:

```
String[][] abriev = {{"United Kingdom", "kilometers"}, {"UK", "km"}};
Map<String, String> abrievMap =
    IntStream.range(0, abriev[0].length)
             .boxed()
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> abriev[0][i], i -> abriev[1][i]));

String origText = "The;coastline;of;United Kingdom;is;12429;kilometers";

String abbreviated =
    Arrays.stream(origText.split(";"))
          .map(word -> abrievMap.getOrDefault(word, word))
          .collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning length of `orgText` to variable `n`:

```
String origText = "The;coastline;of;United Kingdom;is;12429;kilometers";
```

And you have two dimensional array:

```
String[][] abriev = {{"United Kingdom", "kilometers"}, {"UK", "km"}};
```

And you are iterate from `0` to length of `origText`. Also Inside the loop you are trying to access `i`'th index, It cannot be done since your first array only contains two indices(two arrays).

Because of that you when you run the program you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Try to use [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).